# Child Tax Credits are ending. Why would they send me a renewal pack?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-credit

Child Tax Credits are ending in 2024 and eligible users are migrating to Universal Credit.

The letter ending Child Tax Credit payments for someone not moving to Universal Credit nevertheless states that the customer will still receive a renewal pack! What possible purpose would a Child Tax Credits renewal pack for 24/25 serve?

Comment: Q1) Is it known _when_ in 2024 CTC is ending? Is there time for a partial renewal? Q2) Does it say what to do with the renewal pack? In other areas of bureaucracy, it's common to see something like "_You may still receive a ..., if you do, please ignore it_" when the issuance of the "thing" is automated and may not always be stopped in time?

Comment: This article looks like a plausible basis for an answer: https://www.litrg.org.uk/benefits/moving-universal-credit/ending-tax-credits - sounds like the move might happen during 2024/25 rather than at the start of the new tax year, and also there's a "finalisation" process.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I had a look at the link you sent and it made a lot of sense. The 'renewal' pack in this case is simply to declare final actual income for the tax year 23/24, allowing HMRC to make any retrospective adjustments. Would you like to expand that to a full answer so I can accept and give credit to you? :-)

Comment: @EleventhDoctor I'm not all that keen on writing an answer based on a secondary source like that (i.e. a campaign/help group rather than the government themselves) and on a topic I don't actually know anything about. But I'll do it if nothing better shows up :-) Anyone else should feel free to write something though!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it appears that the migration to Universal Credit will only be complete for everyone by the *end* of the 2024/25 tax year, and different people are being told to migrate at different times (see e.g. [1](https://community.hmrc.gov.uk/customerforums/taxcredits/2e37dd20-dbcf-ee11-a81c-6045bd0bc63b), [2](https://www.litrg.org.uk/benefits/moving-universal-credit/ending-tax-credits)).

So it's possible that someone would still need to renew one more time, although from the wording of your question maybe your own migration is already happening.

Secondly, there is some kind of [reconciliation process called "finalisation"](https://www.litrg.org.uk/benefits/moving-universal-credit/ending-tax-credits). It appears to be because the credits are based on estimated income and they need to check you got the right amount from your actual income - see e.g. [this description of provisional versus finalised awards](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/child-and-working-tax-credits-statistics-finalised-annual-awards-2021-to-2022/child-and-working-tax-credits-finalised-annual-awards-2021-to-2022-background-and-definitions#provisional-awards-vs-finalised-awards).

From what I can tell, some people, but not necessarily everyone, have to make a final application to make sure their awards get finalised properly.